# How to keep a copy in Local Computer while deleting from Server?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, backup, microsoft-outlook-2010, local

Alright!!

I'm using Microsoft Outlook (As part of Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010).

When I received "Your mailbox is Full" message, I had deleted some mails from Server using web version. But after the deletion, I couldn't find local copies of those mails in Outlook client as well. I presume, It is in "Synchronized" with server but Couldn't find any option within Outlook client or Web version to control the same. I want to have local copies within Outlook client & at the same time free up some space within Server.

So, How to keep local copies of mails in my Computer even if I remove those from Server??

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: Use POP3 to fetch the mails or move the mails from within Outlook into a separate data file.

Comment: Use the auto archive feature, or manually move files to a separate PST file. Using POP3 instead of an Exchange connection has the same effect but will probably cause you many other headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that the way you described. Outlook uses local automatically synchronized OST cache files for Exchange accounts. If you want to keep your emails locally, backup old emails before deleting them.